# Keep processes active after logging out of RDP

Tags: linux, windows, remote-desktop, vnc, vps

i have a windows dedicated server where i host a music stream on twitch but when i disconnect from it the stream stops working because the windows user is disconnected. How do i prevent the server from pausing the OBS process and continue in the background.

My workaround was to order a cheap linux vps to rdp on it 24h/7 and i would vnc on the linux to access the windows server.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

First thing you do is type 'control userpasswords2' in the run dialogue (Win+R) and make normal login automatic.

Secondly, if you are using RDP - just close the RDP window - do not logout. The session will keep running without issue.

RDP isn't always the best viewing method, so if you are disconnecting and not logging out, use VNC server instead to administer the machine.

Comment: The OP already stated that when he *disconnects* (not logs out) the stream stops.

Comment: Disconnect could mean that he is logging out, or closing. We don't know

Comment: I see your point given the conflicting question title, but given the significance to RDP of the term disconnect, I suspect the OP really means exactly that.

Comment: No services or applications stop when you disconnect, as he mentions. I'm assuming that he's logging out ...

Comment: some applications stop working as expected when a user is disconnected, even though the program could continue running if so designed. It's actually a common problem.

Comment: then how do i stop logging out at the end of a session thanks a lot

Comment: @LeJork you choose *disconnect* on the Start menu of the remote machine, or click the X in the Remote Desktop Connection bar at the top of the remote session's screen.

Comment: @JohnnyVegas it looks like you were correct that the OP is logging out instead of disconnecting! +1 to you.

Comment: Does not work : relogging me in when i disconnect and then reconnect

Comment: Try VNC server to view your server locally instead.